# Looking to add databases of the exact same structure dynamically with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a new client that would like to add connection strings in an admin panel. These strings would point to new databases of the exact same structure. I would store my connection strings in a "main" database and retrieve them at runtime. **I need to "union" all the connection strings and load data from all the databases**. So I would need N number contexts at runtime, I am thinking of using Dependency Injection to create a List of contexts that I could for a foreach through and query and load up all the data I need from all database connections strings stored in my "main" database connstring table.

Or I can do a foreach through the connection strings and recreate the context for each string and load the data from all database into memory.

I know this is difficult solution to achieve, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the databases are with the same structure, why do you need dependency injection? One DbContext definition will cover them all.

You can pass name of the connection string, or connection string itself to DbContext constructor, and thus change the database it will open connection to once you instantiate it.

Here is the link to the constructor you can use:

[MSDN DbContext Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Comment: I need to "union" all connection strings provided though. So you are saying go through each connection string and recreate the context for each connection string and load the data in memory?

Comment: What do you mean by "union" connection strings? I'm not familiar with that concept :( You can iterate through the list of connection strings, and instantiate same DbContext for each, yes. AFAIK there is no easy solution to make cross-database query.

Comment: So in each database there is a Products table, I need to "Union All" all products in all databases. Yes you are right I am sure, I have never heard of such a request as being able to add additional databases in this fashion.